# Why does my right join and inner join query return the same table in my SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables "**People**" and "**Donations**". The People table has three columns "**id**" "**name**" "**city**", and the Donations table has three columns "**id**", "**people_id**", "**donation_date**", "**party**".

The "id" column in people table is the same as "people_id" column in Donations. Now, I create and populate the tables with the following query:

```
create table People(id integer, name varchar(100), country varchar(100));
insert into People(id, name, country) values(1, "Kenji", "Japan");
insert into People(id, name, country) values(2, "Rose", "Australia");
insert into People(id, name, country) values(3, "Vanessa", "France");

create table Donations(id integer, people_id integer, donation_date date, party varchar(20));
insert into Donations(id, people_id, donation_date, party) values(1,1, '2012-02-10',"Democrat");
insert into Donations(id, people_id, donation_date, party) values(2,1, '2012-02-10',"Republican");
```

The problem is the following two query basically returns the same thing except the row order is different:

```
select *
from People inner join
     Donations
     on People.id = Donations.people_id;
 


select *
from People right join
     Donations
     on People.id = Donations.people_id;
```

The left join works as intended with null values from the right table (Donations table):

```
select *
from People left join
     Donations
     on People.id = Donations.people_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Donations` only references one `person_id`.  That `person_id` is in `People`.

Hence, all rows match, and the results are the same as the inner join.

Nothing surprising.

Comment: Even if donations references more than one person_id. It will be display the same result as the inner join

Comment: @Rongeegee . . . It would only have different results if there were `person_id`s that did not match.

Answer (score 0):

The key is who is the "Boss"
`select * from People inner join Donations on People.id = Donations.people_id;`
When using `inner join`, "People" and "Donations" are both "Boss"

`select * from People left join Donations on People.id = Donations.people_id;`
When using `left join`, the People on the left side of the connection are "Boss", and the existence of "Donations" is not important.

`select * from People right join Donations on People.id = Donations.people_id;`
When using `right join`, the "Donations" on the right side of the connection is "Boss" and the existence of "People" is not important.

Not important means it can be "NULL"

So when "People" and "Donations" swap positions, `right join` and `left join` can also be swapped and get the same result.
E.g
`select * from People left join Donations on People.id = Donations.people_id;`
`select * from Donations right join People on People.id = Donations.people_id;`

Comment: speaking of being not important and being null, how come "select * from People left join Donations on People.id = Donations.people_id;" does not return the rest the rows with "null" values on the first few columns?

Comment: take a look at my newly edited content .its return is in order.